# Insert space between numbers and letters in currency formatted text

Tags: java, regex, currency, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I have a string "eur0.99", it can be "eur123.0" or "som0.10", or "0.99usd", or "123.34any" or something like that. How can I simply insert a space between the price and letters without making a huge nasty messy code?

Comment: *or something like that* is not very descriptive. What exactly do you have and what exactly do you want?

Comment: @Tunaki well, I provided 5 different examples. You know it was quite easy to understand what I meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", " "));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/C4AE7l)**

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it

Comment: @Gintas_ you are welcome